# How to set rules in firebase firestore and realtime?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

**In firebase firestore:**
I have a three different collections, 1:- "users", 2:- "ContactUs", 3rd "Reports".
In users, document is created by uid and then it has a field inside by the name of "uid".
In ContactUs and Reports, document is generated randomly and it is different every time.

I have tried the following rules but I am not sure about it, pls help me to correct it. In ContactUs and Reports, is there should be {userId} or something else as it is different each time and how I am going to compare it with uid as there is no field of uid inside them?

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /users/{userId} {
  allow write, update, delete: if
      request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
    
}
match /ContactUs/{userId} {  
  allow write, update, delete: if
      request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
    
}
match /Reports/{userId} {
  allow write, update, delete: if
      request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
    
  }

 }
}
```

**In realtime database:** I have attached a photo for reference which shows details of child created at the time of users starts new chat.[image]

I have tried the following rules in realtime but it says:- Your security rules are not secure. Any authenticated user can steal, modify, or delete data in your database.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Pls help me to set them correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore rules work same as code CSS. It reads from up to bottom and rule below can overwrite rule before. So first you should restrict access to whole database.

This rule should be at the top of all rules.

```js
match /{document=**} {
   allow read, write: if false;
}
```

`write` word is equal to all words together `create, update, delete` so use those words separatly for diferent conditions or just `write` word.

If i whare you i would make rules for users collection like this:

```js
match /users/{userId} {
  allow create, update: if 
     request.auth != null && request.resource.id == request.auth.uid;
  allow read: if request.auth != null && userId == request.auth.uid;
}
```

In example above user can create/update document if his request document has same `id` as his `uid` and can read if document id he request is equal to his `uid`. In this rules there are no delete operation so he will cant delete his document.

realtime database works really similar but you have to get to know on your own how to make rules.

Comment: and what about ContactUs and Reports collection. do I need to make different rules for them or not like match /ContactUs/ {userId}{..........

Comment: About other doc in collection if you want user to be able to create many documents create a field like `isOwner` with his uid and wrote rule that only person who is owner can read update delete. And any one logged in can create a new document.

Comment: It will be some thing like this: `resource.data.isOwner == request.auth.uid`